# Is there a way to quick filter lists in ServiceNow?

Tags: servicenow

I'm putting together reports, when i double click any item in a bar graph, it appears with a quick-filter/search option, is there a way to get this on normal list reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are viewing a normal list or table there is a way to quick sort to match a specific category.  Whether you are trying to match or filter out a category under the table, all you have to do is **right click** on the desired status and options should appear to either **show matching**, or **filter out**!

This works with things like trying to filter out specific users, status, or individual projects.  These are just a few examples you are able to apply this to.  Really any table with sub-categories shown are filterable!

I hope this answers your question!